# Query to get rows with same value in 3 columns and different in 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a lot of data, I need to get the rows which IdMod, TableName and FieldName columns match in 2 or more rows.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT aa.Id, aa.IdMod, aa.TableName, aa.FieldName, aa.OldValue, aa.NewValue, aa.Origin, aa.Destination, aa.CreationDate, aa.Discard
FROM Process aa 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT IdMod, TableName, FieldName
            FROM Process
            GROUP BY  IdMod, TableName, FieldName
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            ) bb
ON aa.IdMod = bb.IdMod AND aa.TableName = bb.TableName AND aa.FieldName = bb.FieldName
WHERE Destination='All' OR Destination=@dest OR Origin=@dest
ORDER BY IdMod,TableName, FieldName
```

With this query i get it:

[image: Result]

But i want get it only if Origin column is not the same. I mean, in this result i want get all except rows 6 and 7, because IdMod, TableName and FieldName match, but Origin also match. Same way, i dont want rows 8 and 9.
However, i want rows 3, 4 and 5 because at least one of them has diferent Origin. Of course, i want 1 and 2 because Origin is diferent.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can improve subquery `bb` by checking column Origin

```
SELECT IdMod, TableName, FieldName 
FROM Process
GROUP BY  IdMod, TableName, FieldName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT Origin) > 1
```

Comment: U.u Ok, so easy... hahaha This work perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Checking `MIN(Origin) <> MAX(Origin)` should be faster than `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.